# Gulp Bundle + Browserify on multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, jsx

So I have asimple gulp task function which currently converts my main.jsx to a main.js file:

```
gulp.task("bundle", function () {
    return browserify({
        entries: "./app/main.jsx",
        debug: true
    }).transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("main.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/dist"))
});
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to put multiple bundles in this gulp.task?
**My ideal outcome would be being able to do:**

- main.jsx to main.js
- otherPage.jsx to otherPage.js
- otherPage2.jsx to otherPage2.js

All in one gulp task.

I have searched onliine but cannot seem to find anything relevant, any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want them in the one bundle?

Comment: I dont mind how I do it, I just wanted to be able to do multiple files at once. @cartant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create a bundle for each file you need to loop over the respective files, create a stream for each file and then merge the streams afterwards (using [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream)):

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task("bundle", function () {
  var files = [ "main", "otherPage", "otherPage2" ];
  return merge(files.map(function(file) {
    return browserify({
        entries: "./app/" + file + ".jsx",
        debug: true
    }).transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(file + ".js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/dist"))
  }));
});
```

The above requires that you maintain a list of files manually as an array. It's also possible to write a task that bundles all `.jsx` files in the `app` directory without having to maintain an explicit array of the files. You just need the [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package to determine the array of files for you:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task("bundle", function () {
  var files = glob.sync('./app/*.jsx');
  return merge(files.map(function(file) {
    return browserify({
        entries: file,
        debug: true
    }).transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(path.basename(file, '.jsx') + ".js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/dist"))
  }));
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to `merge`?